# FB post likes count

Tags: ios, facebook-like

I have a post that has 15k likes. But the max limit is 1000 per page.
So is there a way I can fetch all 15k in one statement?

I don't wanna loop through till the end.

This is what I tried but the limit is 1000 a request

```
FBRequest *like = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"558620397509180?fields=likes.limit(100000)"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you cannot fetch them all in one statement. Facebook has placed restrictions on how their API can be used and this is one of them.

The best I can think of is to retrieve them in several consequtive queries.